# What's the difference between chunk and block in lua

Tags: lua

what's the difference between chunk and block in lua? I can not understand what is chunk!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has been asked and addressed here: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-06/threads.html#00723

From the 5.2 Manual:

> The unit of execution of Lua is called a chunk. Syntactically, a chunk is simply a block: `chunk ::= block`

From the mouth of Roberto:

> The fact that a chunk is a block does not mean that any block is a
>   chunk. Chunks do not nest (unlike blocks). A chunk is an outermost block
>   which you feed to "load".

Answer (score 6):

A chunk is an independently executable sequence of statements. A block is just a sequence of statements. The difference is that a chunk can be executed independently of other chunks.

All chunks are blocks (sequences of statements), but not all blocks are chunks.

A chunk is basically a Lua *function*; you can call it with some parameters, and it will return 0 or more values. That's what I mean by "independently executable": the statements within a chunk will be executed in order. But once you exit a chunk, what chunk you execute next is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

A block can be a chunk of code. However, a block usually means zero or more statements belonging to, for example, an `if` statement, or function.

A quote from the [official Lua reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.2):

> *[...] A block is a list of statements; syntactically, a block is the same as a chunk [...]*

If you look at [the grammar of Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8), you can see that they're the same:

```
chunk ::= {stat [`;´]} [laststat [`;´]]

block ::= chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

Block is Sub part Of Chunk they could be same some times as in code example 02:
for example 01:

```
 if condition1 then
        block1
    elseif condition2 then
        block2
    elseif condition3 then
        block3
    else
        block4
    end
```

over here we have one chunk starting from
    if condition1 then to last end
    but this code have four blocks every condition have separate block.
this example have one chunk & four blocks.

Example 02:

```
   /////////////////////////// 01 //////////////////////
for variable = beginning, end, step do
        block
    end
   /////////////////////////// 02 //////////////////////
function Name()
        block
    end

   /////////////////////////// 03 //////////////////////
 if condition then
        block
    end
```

in example 02 chunk & block is same but always they are not same.
please read yourself.

http://www.lua.org/manual/2.5/manual.html

**4.4.1 - Blocks**

A block is a list of statements, which are executed sequentially. Any statement can be optionally followed by a semicolon:

block := {stat sc} [ret]
sc := [';']

**2 - Environment and Chunks**

The unit of execution of Lua is called a chunk. The syntax for chunks is:

chunk := {stat | function} [ret]

is it helpful ?????

Comment: @booirror if it is useful then do not forget to select it as answer & up arrow.

Comment: yeah,chunk consist of blocks.do you think so?

Comment: yeah, i think chunk consist of blocks (single or multiple) of single structure which ends normally with end.

Comment: They are the same. You're linking to Lua documentation from 1997! That is more than 15 years ago. Read the reference I posted, which is from Lua 5.1 and clearly states they're practically the same thing.